# how to get return response from AWS Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, python-2.7, aws-lambda

I have a simple lambda function that returns a dict response and another lambda function invokes that function and prints the response.

**lambda function A**

```
def handler(event,context):
    params = event['list']
    return {"params" : params + ["abc"]}
```

**lambda function B invoking A**

```
a=[1,2,3]
x = {"list" : a}
invoke_response = lambda_client.invoke(FunctionName="monitor-workspaces-status",
                                       InvocationType='Event',
                                       Payload=json.dumps(x))
print (invoke_response)
```

**invoke_response**

```
{u'Payload': <botocore.response.StreamingBody object at 0x7f47c58a1e90>, 'ResponseMetadata': {'HTTPStatusCode': 202, 'RequestId': '9a6a6820-0841-11e6-ba22-ad11a929daea'}, u'StatusCode': 202}
```

Why is the response status 202? Also, how can I get the response data from invoke_response? I could not find a clear documentation of how to do it.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

A `202` response means `Accepted`.  It is a successful response but is telling you that the action you have requested has been initiated but has not yet completed.  The reason you are getting a `202` is because you invoked the Lambda function asynchronously.  Your `InvocationType` parameter is set to `Event`.  If you want to make a synchronous call, change this to `RequestResponse`.

Once you do that, you can get the returned data like this:

```
data = invoke_response['Payload'].read()
```

Comment: made my day! Thanks a lot. Haven't found this anywhere in docs

Comment: `.read()` returns type `bytes` so if you were expecting a string, JSON, etc., you have to `.decode()` them. e.g. `response['Payload'].read().decode()`

Comment: And since `json.dumps(obj)` returns a quoted string, (**if you used that** for the `return` value of your `lambda_handler`) you are going to get a string if you do `json.loads(response['Payload'].read().decode())' and would have to wrap another `json.loads()` around that. So, don't explicitly convert to JSON in your lambda function.

Comment: Is there a way to get a callback after completion for invocation type Event?

Comment: @2ank3th I had the same issue, and I looked up in the AWS documentation. It says, for `Event` type invocations, there is no response body: [open aws documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/zh_cn/lambda/latest/dg/API_Invoke.html#API_Invoke_ResponseSyntax)

Comment: A bit shorter construct would be: `json.loads(json.load(response['Payload']))`.

Comment: This works to me:
responseFromChild = json.load(invoke_response['Payload'])
print("responseFromChild", responseFromChild)

Answer (score 2):

try: `data = invoke_response['Payload'].read()`
read() because it is a StreamingBody object

```
<botocore.response.StreamingBody object at 0x110b91c50>
```

It is in the boto3 docs. You can find more details about this here: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/resources.html#actions