# Call AWS lambda function from an existing lambda function on Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, aws-lambda

I'm trying to call another lambda function from an existing lambda fucntion as below (python 2.7)

```
from __future__ import print_function
import boto3
import json

lambda_client = boto3.client('lambda')

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    invoke_response = lambda_client.invoke(FunctionName="teststack",
                                           InvocationType='RequestResponse'
                                           )
    print(invoke_response)

    return str(invoke_response)
```

I'm gettting the below response instead of an actual result. When I run teststack lambda invidually it works fine, but getting below response instead of "test" returned by the `teststack` Lambda function.

```
{u'Payload': <botocore.response.StreamingBody object at ****>, 'ResponseMetadata': {'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'RequestId': '******', 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid': '******', 'content-length': '155', 'x-amzn-remapped-content-length': '0', 'connection': 'keep-alive', 'date': 'Sun, 17 Jul 2016 21:02:01 GMT', 'content-type': 'application/json'}}, u'StatusCode': 200}
```

Comment: i got solution from this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36784925/how-to-get-return-response-from-aws-lambda-function?rq=1 THanks!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get return response from AWS Lambda function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36784925/how-to-get-return-response-from-aws-lambda-function)

Comment: @Gricey, the other question deals with asynchronous call (HTTP 202, "Event"). Here it's a synchronous call (HTTP 200, "RequestResponse"). So... Not a duplicate. At least not this one.

Comment: @GrzegorzOledzki the answer to the duplicate I link says that they should be using `RequestResponse`. However I've added an answer so that there's something here for the question as asked.

Answer (score 20):

The response data you're looking for is there, it's just inside the `Payload` as a [StreamingBody](http://botocore.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/response.html#botocore.response.StreamingBody) object.

According to the Boto docs, you can read the object using the `read` method:

```
invoke_response['Payload'].read()
```